# Get customer ID inside phtml file used in order email

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email-templates, customer-account, order-email

I am using a .phtml file which I pull into the order email **I need to use the customer ID inside this .phtml file inside a function to pass back a value to my email, how can I get this information inside this .phtml file**? My code is below:

```
$customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customerId = $customerData->getId();
```

Do I need to be looking at an order collection rather than the customer? If so what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: question seems to be confused.Please clarify this question  `I need to use the customer ID inside this .phtml file inside a function to pass back a value to my email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can do the following directly in your email template:

```
{{var order.getCustomerId()}}
```

However, it seems like this is not totally what you.

What I suggest you to do is create a custom handle under your module XML file or under your `local.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <custom_handle_sales_order_email>
        <block type="core/template" name="custom" template="path/to/your/template.phtml" />
    </custom_handle_sales_order_email>
</layout>
```

Then in your email template you can add the following :

```
{{layout handle="custom_handle_sales_order_email" order=$order}}
```

Finally in your `path/to/your/template.phtml` file you can do:

```
$order = $this->getOrder();
$customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to do this in my phtml file though as I need to pass the ID into a function in there

Comment: @KiwisTasteGood Hmmmm, your question is misleading. I understand that you only need the customer id and not something else

Comment: Edited the question, hope it's more clear

Comment: @KiwisTasteGood see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks very much it was the last bit I had wrong!! Thanks again :)